# Mongodb: how to update a field only if the value I want to upload is not null?

Tags: mongodb

I have a field named "profilePicture" that can have a string or a null value. When editing his profile, a user may or may not upload a new profile image. This mean that I can either receive a string or a null value.

How to update profilePicture only if the new value is not null (so I can keep the existing string )?

Here is the code:

```js
const newProfilePicture = null // can be null or "string"
const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        userId,
        [{$set: { profilePicture: newProfilePicture }}]
        { new: true }
      );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const updateObj = {};
// other properties added to object
// e.g.
// updateObj.name = "DoneDeal0";

if (newProfilePicture !== null) {
 updateObj.profilePicture = "https://profilepicture.etc/picture.jpg";
}

const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  { userId:"someID" }, 
  { $set: updateObj }, 
  { new: true }
);
```

Use conditional logic to build an object prior to your mongo query.

Comment: It would be a great option, but I will always update many fields. profilePicture is only one among 20+. For the sake of code's clarity, I only talked about this field. Some fields have $concat, $filter, $not and $in operators. So I don't think such an update would be compatible with an object.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using application logic. You can check beforehand if `newProfilePicture` is null, and if not perform the update. Something like this:

```
const newProfilePicture = null;
if (newProfilePicture){
  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
          userId,
          [{$set: { profilePicture: newProfilePicture }}]
          { new: true }
        );
}
```

If you need to return `user` regardless of whether an update actually occurs, you can just add an `else` branch and do a normal `findById`:

```
const newProfilePicture = null;
if (newProfilePicture){
  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
          userId,
          [{$set: { profilePicture: newProfilePicture }}]
          { new: true }
        );
} else {
  const user = await User.findById(userId);
}
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but I will always update many fields. profilePicture is only one among 20+. For the sake of code's clarity, I only talked about this field. I don't think duplicating such a big update function would be the best option.